# cannot execute iexplore.exe when I create a symbolic link to it

Tags: windows, wine, browser, ie

I do something like:

```
$ ln -s '/home/deostroll/.wine/dosdevices/c:/Program Files/Internet Explorer/iexplore.exe' /usr/bin/iexplore
```

I am expecting that at the shell I can just type the following and expect the Internet explorer browser window to show up:

```
$ pwd
<where ever>
$ iexplore
```

But instead I get the following error message:

```
wine: cannot find L"Z:\\usr\\bin\\iexplore."
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you need to create a script (a wrapper of sorts) to make WINE find the .exe correctly.

Here's an example:

- Create the link (as you did in your question).
- Open a text editor and type the following:

  ```
  wine /path/to/link
  ```
- Save the file as `iexplore`.
- Make the file executable.
- Place this file in `/usr/bin.`

---

An alternative method (if the link still causes issues) is to copy the iexplore.exe file `/usr/bin` and simply tell the script to point to it:

`wine iexplore.exe`

---

A third option would be to point the script directly to the file:

`wine /path/to/iexplore.exe`

Comment: but don't u think that `wine` is implicitly being called since I can see `wine: cannot find L"Z:\\usr\\bin\\iexplore.` as error message!

Comment: A hard link is probably enough.

Comment: @VineetMenon wine isn't being called correctly and probably is being fickle, so it is better to point wine directly to the executable (especially when using the command-line).

Answer (score 0):

First - remove the link you created, it's no good, then -

You could try this - though i'd probably copy to /usr/local/bin or ~/bin instead

```
sudo cp /usr/bin/notepad /usr/bin/iexplore
```

Then either move iexplore.exe to your  ~/.wine/drive_c/windows or ~/.wine/drive_c/windows/system32 folder or do a link to it in either

Ex.

```
 ln -s '/home/deostroll/.wine/dosdevices/c:/Program Files/Internet Explorer/iexplore.exe' '/home/deostroll/.wine/dosdevices/c:/windows/'
```

Then the command iexplore should open iexplore.exe  (whatever that is

What this does is create a wine wrapper script named iexplore which will run iexplore.exe in wine